# How can I add resilience to a minimum spanning tree?

Tags: graph-theory, trees, network

I have a complete, weighted, undirected graph. The edge weights are the cost of a connection between two nodes, so the minimum spanning tree is the subset of the edges with the lowest total cost such that the graph remains connected.

The MST must be connected at all times, but unfortunately the connections aren't very reliable, so I would like to add redundancy to this graph/network.

Is it possible to compute a subset of edges such that the total edge cost is minimised *and* edge-connectivity is over a certain minimum?

Comment: An other way to add redundancy is to look for a subset of edges which is a union of edges of edge-disjoint spanning trees and the number of trees is over a certain minimum.